# Does this code return the latest date PER product?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to get the latest date per product ID:

`SELECT ProductID, Max(Date) as Date FROM MyTable GROUP BY ProductID`

I was always under the impression I had to do a nested join, but this appears to work!

EDIT: Thanks for all replies

Comment: As per my answer to your other question today; the nested join allows you to lso see other fields in `MyTable` that are associated to that MAX(Date) `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That's what aggregates do!**

For each unique value of `ProductId`, return the maximum `Date` value.  Not nested `JOIN` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. It returns the biggest value of the column `Date` of all rows with the same `ProductID`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, per `ProductId` being exact. If it represents Product and there **exists** `Date` for this product - then completely YES

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. You would need to use a nested `JOIN` if you were wanting to retrieve other columns in addition to the `ProductID` columns from the table. E.g:

```
SELECT ProductID, Quantity, ...
FROM MyTable
JOIN
(
    SELECT ProductID, Max(Date) AS Date 
    FROM MyTable 
    GROUP BY ProductID
) T1 ON MyTable.ProductID = T1.ProductID AND MyTable.Date = T1.Date;
```

Comment: Just like on your answer to the OPs previous question :)